# How do I write about "fun" without using that word?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms, writing, phrase-usage

I'm a fortunate writer in that I get to write about toys. I get to describe games, puzzles and many more fun things for kids and adults. But I'm feeling like a broken record that's relying on the word "fun" too much. What are other ways to call something "fun" without using that word?

I'm trying to go beyond the thesaurus. I'm writing about an emotional response so I'm looking for similar words people like and respond to. Thanks for your help.

Comment: [amusing, enjoyable, entertaining, lively, pleasant, boisterous, convivial, diverting, merry, witty,...](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fun) That's what a thesaurus is for.

Comment: What is *fun*? How does it make people feel? What is going on that someone says *this is fun*? *Fun* is a cop-out, *par excellence* - a platitude. Wiki begins its description of such. "A platitude is a trite,meaningless, or prosaic statement, generally directed at quelling social, emotional, or cognitive unease. Platitudes are geared towards presenting a shallow, unifying wisdom over a difficult topic. However, they are too overused and general to be anything more than undirected statements with ultimately little meaningful contribution towards a solution". Think, what do you mean by *fun*?

Comment: Also compelling, enthralling, gripping, captivating, exciting, thrilling, etc.

Comment: Writing advice is off topic. You might look at the guidelines for Writers stack exchange and see if your question would be on topic there.

Comment: This isn't really asking for writing advice. I'm looking for what other words people prefer using. A thesaurus is fine and I use it daily, but I wanted to expand. Since I'm writing about an emotion and emotional responses, I wanted more human input that what's in a thesaurus.

Comment: As for what I mean by "fun" it's simply something that brings enjoyment. Likes toys, games and puzzles do.

Comment: [Fun is when you...fun is like...it's like... it's kinda...sorta like a...what _is_ fun?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqhfLTsEeZg)

Comment: There really isn't a single meaning for _fun_; sensory/emotional terms like that just mean 'I like it'. If you want variation, think and talk about the different kinds of things and activities that **you** think are fun, or better yet, ask the kids who test your stuff to talk about it, in as many different languages as they speak. You'll get tons of metaphors, and that's what you really need.

Comment: @ColinMilroy You have a perfectly good question that just does not fit with what this site is about. English.SE gives definitive answers to questions about English. You are looking for opinions, maybe discussion, personal preferences, and such questions cannot be answered definitively. If you feel Writers.SE isn't the place for your question, you might try our Chat.

Comment: The Chat looks good but I don't have the requisite reputation points.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can go into more detail when describing the fun experienced by describing *how* fun it is.

For example, **engaging** can be used to describe that its not only fun, but maintaining your interest. When I write, phrases like **having a blast** can also flavor the text beyond "it was fun" and evoke certain impressions in readers. I have also personally come into the habit of using words like **enthralling** or **riveting** to illustrate more gasp-worthy impressions.

As a general rule of thumb, when a reviewer describes things that are entertaining (or not), it is paramount to qualify those reactions with *why* said feelings are drawn out. "I had fun even when it wasn't my turn" seems weird and almost clinical compared to "I found myself awaiting every player's move with bated breath" when describing gameplay elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use synonyms like:

> Joy. Merry. Mirth. Having a good time. Having an enjoyable time, or even "enjoying yourself".